# Copy cells containing specific word to cell on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data:

[image]

I have two sheets.

```
1 = RESULTS
2 = DASHBOARD
```

I am looking for a formula that searches sheet **RESULTS** column **A:A** (whole column) for the word **"Host name"**, and then copies the "Host name" to sheet **DASHBOARD** cell **A1**.

IF POSSIBLE: (Using above image as example) I would appreciate it if the formula could search for "Host name" and then before copying it to cell **A1**, remove the word "**Host Name:**" (with colon). So the result copied will only be **USER-PC**.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this formula in `DASHBOARD cell A1` :

```
=MID(INDEX(RESULTS!A:A, MATCH("Host name:*", RESULTS!A:A,0)), 2+LEN("Host name:"),1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with vba but it's more complicated that way:

```
Dim FindString As String
FindString = "Host Name: "
Dim Rng As Range

    With Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rng.row).Value = Replace(Rng.Text, "Host Name:", "")
    End With
End If
```

Comment: I changed my code, which had asked for an input, that's why it's still there. I will change it.

Comment: aha, makes more sense now :)

Comment: Thanks Svekke for your VBA script and your input!